# Place explicit character tokens of category 1/2, whose character codes are to be specified, before/behind tokens that form arbitrary macro argument?

Tags: macros, tex-core, braces

Assume tokens
<kbd><sub>\macro</sub></kbd><kbd>{<sub>1</sub></kbd><kbd>6<sub>12</sub></kbd><kbd>5<sub>12</sub></kbd><kbd>}<sub>2</sub></kbd><kbd>{<sub>1</sub></kbd><kbd>6<sub>12</sub></kbd><kbd>6<sub>12</sub></kbd><kbd>}<sub>2</sub></kbd><kbd>{<sub>1</sub></kbd><kbd>*⟨arbitrary non-outer brace balanced tokens⟩*</kbd><kbd>}<sub>2</sub></kbd>;

- the 1st argument of `\macro` holds a TeX-⟨number⟩-quantity in the range of possible codepoints of the TeX engine's internal character encoding scheme which denotes the character code of the explicit category 1 character token to create;
- the 2nd argument of `\macro` holds a TeX-⟨number⟩-quantity in the range of possible codepoints of the TeX engine's internal character encoding scheme which denotes the character code of the explicit category 2 character token to create;
- the 3rd argument of `\macro` holds an arbitrary amount of non-outer brace balanced tokens that are to be placed between the explicit category 1 character token and the explicit category 2 character token.

How to define an expandable macro `\macro` in Knuth's TeX—`\expanded` not available, where expansion at some stage delivers
<kbd>A<sub>1</sub></kbd><kbd>*⟨arbitrary non-outer brace balanced tokens⟩*</kbd><kbd>B<sub>2</sub></kbd> ?

How to define an expandable macro `\macro` for an (elder) utf-8-engine with `\expanded` not being available, where expansion at some stage delivers
<kbd>A<sub>1</sub></kbd><kbd>*⟨arbitrary non-outer brace balanced tokens⟩*</kbd><kbd>B<sub>2</sub></kbd> ?

---

With `\expanded`/expl3 available you can do s.th. along

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \macro #1#2#3 
  {
    \tex_expanded:D { \char_generate:nn {#1}{1}
                      \exp_not:n {#3}
                      \char_generate:nn {#2}{2}
                    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

If expandability was not an issue, one could do s.th. along

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newtoks\scratch
\cs_new:Npn \macro #1#2#3 
  {
    \scratch={#3}
    \exp_after:wN \def
    \exp_after:wN \test 
    \exp_after:wN {
     \exp:w
     \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
     \exp_after:wN
     \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
     \exp_end: 
     \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
     \exp_after:wN
     \char_generate:nn {#1}{1}
     \the \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \scratch \char_generate:nn {#2}{2}
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

---

It is academical interest. I try to learn how TeX works in order to gain a good understanding of what you can do and what you can't. And how. I think that approach is better than to start by trying to write documents and getting stuck all the time while approaching the deadline.

I know expl3 is LaTeX, but the only real expl3-thing I use is `\char_generate:nn` and according to source3.pdf that is fully functional with traditional LaTeX (8 bit engines) also, which implies that a stripped down variant only delivering explicit character tokens of category 1/2 can also be implemented using plain tex.
E.g., one could define a macro for each code point which with two expansion-steps, `\romannumeral`-expansion and brace-hacking delivers the character token in question.

Comment: why the restriction to classic tex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because I seem to already know how to do it using `\expanded`. I don't have practical use for this yet - I want to learn what's possible and what's not and what I overlook.

Comment: do you require this to be _expandable_ ? I doubt that's possible in classic tex.

Comment: but latex for example is not usable in classic tex, pdftex isn't classic tex plain tex has etex available. so the restriction is like asking to do it in tex2 or tex-in-sail, possibly of academic interest but of no practical use

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I require expandabilitym because I seem to know hiow to do it when expandability is not an issue. ;-)

Comment: not expl3, etex (and `\expanded`) you can not build a latex format with classic tex. traditional 8 bit engines means _pdftex_ so including `\expanded` it does not mean classic tex without etex,

Comment: I provide a classic tex version in the posted answer but that is _not_ what is meant by char_generate comment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just looked into source2e.pdf and source3.pdf and saw that - as you said -nowadays you can't build latex with classic TeX. But seems only few years ago there was LaTeX, also not buildable with classic TeX, but which came without `\expanded`. I don't know how much time needs to pass by in the TeX community until one can safely assume users having `\expanded` available.

Comment: When I saw the title with `category 1/2` I thought maybe that `catcode` was now using quantum mechanical spin. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to do this but if you define 256*256 helper functions you could do

```
\def\macro#1#2{%
  \csname x\number#1x\number#2\endcsname
  }


  % then lots of definitions like

  {\catcode65=1\relax \catcode66=2\relax
  \expandafter
  \gdef\csname x65x66\endcsname#1{A#1B}
}


\immediate\write20
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter
{%
  \macro{65}{66}{some \relax \alpha tokens}%
}

\bye
```

Answer (score 3):

When [David Carlisle pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709624/301872) the right direction I realized that one can do with (256·2)+3 helper macros instead of 256<sup>2</sup>:

```
\newcount\scratch
\long\def\gobble#1{}%
\chardef\nomoreromannumeral=0 %

\long\def\PlaceCategoryTwoTokenBehindArgument#1#2{%
  \endgroup
  %---------------------------------------------------------
  \expandafter\def
  \csname PlaceACategoryOneToken\number\scratch\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\nomoreromannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1%
  }%
  %---------------------------------------------------------
  \long\expandafter\def
  \csname PlaceACategoryTwoToken\number\scratch BehindArgument\endcsname##1{%
    \expandafter\gobble\string#2%
  }%
}%

% Character with code-point number 0 = Character ^^@ cannot
% be lowercased,see TeXbook, so needs treatment outside
% lowercase loop:
%---------------------------------------------------------
\catcode0=1\relax
\expandafter\def
\csname PlaceACategoryOneToken0\endcsname{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\nomoreromannumeral
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter^^@\expandafter\gobble\string}%
}%
%---------------------------------------------------------
\catcode0=2\relax
\long\expandafter\def
\csname PlaceACategoryTwoToken0BehindArgument\endcsname#1{%
  \expandafter\gobble\string{#1^^@%
}%
%---------------------------------------------------------
\catcode0=9\relax

\catcode`\X=1\relax
\catcode`\Y=2\relax

\scratch=0\relax
\loop
\ifnum\scratch<255 %
  \advance\scratch by 1 %
  %---------------------------------------------------------
  \begingroup
  \lccode`\X=\scratch\relax
  \lccode`\Y=\scratch\relax
  \lowercase{\PlaceCategoryTwoTokenBehindArgument{X\expandafter\gobble\string}}{{##1Y}}%
  %---------------------------------------------------------
\repeat

\catcode`\X=11\relax
\catcode`\Y=11\relax


\long\def\PlaceCategoryTwoTokenBehindArgument#1#2{%
  \csname PlaceACategoryTwoToken\number#2BehindArgument\endcsname{#1}%
}%
\def\PlaceCategoryOneToken#1{%
  \csname PlaceACategoryOneToken\number#1\endcsname
}%
\long\def\macro#1#2#3{%
  \romannumeral\PlaceCategoryTwoTokenBehindArgument{\PlaceCategoryOneToken{#1}#3}{#2}%
}%

% A test:
\newtoks\testtoks

\testtoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \macro{65}{66}{\fi#\endcsname\iffalse ##\UndeFInED\egroup\par\csname\if\bgroup}%
}%
\edef\test{\the\testtoks}%
\show\test

\bye
```

---

Edit:

After [Joseph Wright](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65188379#65188379) gave the challenge in chat I realized that one can do with 256+5 helper macros:

```
\newcount\scratch
\long\def\gobble#1{}%
\long\def\fot#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\sot#1#2{#2}%
\chardef\nomoreromannumeral=0 %
\chardef\MyOne=1 %

% Character with code-point number 0 = Character ^^@ cannot
% be lowercased,see TeXbook, so needs treatment outside
% lowercase loop:
%---------------------------------------------------------
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^@=1\relax
\def\fot{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter^^@\expandafter\gobble\string}}%
\catcode`\^^@=2\relax
\def\sot{\expandafter\gobble\string{^^@}%
\edef\fot{%
  \endgroup
  \long\noexpand\expandafter\def
  \noexpand\csname PlaceACategoryOneOrTwoToken0BehindArgument\noexpand\endcsname##1##2{%
    \noexpand\ifnum##1=\nomoreromannumeral
    \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\fot\noexpand\else\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\sot\noexpand\fi
    {%
      \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\gobble\noexpand\string{##2\sot
    }{%
      \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\nomoreromannumeral
      \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\fot
      \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\gobble\noexpand\string}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\fot

%---------------------------------------------------------
\long\def\PlaceCategoryOneOrTwoTokenBehindArgument#1#2{%
  \long\expandafter\def
  \csname PlaceACategoryOneOrTwoToken\the\scratch BehindArgument\endcsname##1##2{%
    \ifnum##1=\nomoreromannumeral\expandafter\fot\else\expandafter\sot\fi
    {%
      \expandafter\gobble\string#1%
    }{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\nomoreromannumeral
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#2%
    }%
  }%
}%
%---------------------------------------------------------

\catcode`\X=1\relax
\catcode`\Y=2\relax

\scratch=0\relax
\loop
\ifnum\scratch<255 %
  \advance\scratch by 1 %
  %---------------------------------------------------------
  \begingroup
  \lccode`\X=\scratch\relax
  \lccode`\Y=\scratch\relax
  \lowercase{%
    \endgroup
    \PlaceCategoryOneOrTwoTokenBehindArgument{{##2Y}{X\expandafter\gobble\string}}%
  }%
  %---------------------------------------------------------
\repeat

\catcode`\X=11\relax
\catcode`\Y=11\relax

\long\def\PlaceCategoryOneOrTwoTokenBehindArgument#1{%
  \csname PlaceACategoryOneOrTwoToken\number#1BehindArgument\endcsname
}%

\long\def\macro#1#2#3{%
  \romannumeral\PlaceCategoryOneOrTwoTokenBehindArgument{#2}{\nomoreromannumeral}{%
    \PlaceCategoryOneOrTwoTokenBehindArgument{#1}{\MyOne}{}#3%
  }%
}%


% A test:
\newtoks\testtoks

\testtoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \macro{65}{66}{\fi#\endcsname\iffalse ##\UndeFInED\egroup\par\csname\if\bgroup}%
}%
\edef\test{\the\testtoks}%
\show\test

\bye
```

Now I am interested if there is an expandable variant which also does on utf8-engines where you don't have `\expanded`. (1,114,112 code-points as in unicode would require a lot of helper macros...)

Comment: `\chardef\nomoreromannumeral=\`\^^00` is just `\chardef\nomoreromannumeral=0` and so unlike `\`\^^0`  the token `\nomoreromannumeral` has no effect on expansion of the following token

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for having a look.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle a) You are right: ```\chardef\nomoreromannumeral=`\^^00 ``` indeed is a complicated way of saying `\chardef\nomoreromannumeral=0 `. (A ⟨normal integer⟩ of kind  backtick⟨character token⟩⟨one optional space⟩ instead of <integer constant⟩⟨one optional space⟩.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle b) But `\nomoreromanumeral` is ⟨chardef-token⟩. TeXbook says in chapter "24 Summary of Vertical Mode" that ⟨chardef-token⟩ is ⟨internal integer⟩ which in turn is a kind of ⟨normal integer⟩ and that unlike with other kinds of ⟨normal integer⟩/⟨internal integer⟩ with this kind of ⟨internal integer⟩ no trailing ⟨one optional space⟩ is searched. So when `\romannumeral` - after doing the expansion you want - finds non-positive ⟨internal integer⟩, then you don't get any token in return **and** TeX does not keep on expanding things for finding components of `\romannumeral`'s ⟨number⟩.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So there are subtle differences which let me prefer ⟨chardef token⟩ for ending `\romannumeral`-expansion:

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ```\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00 \def\ten{10}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\test\expandafter{\romannumeral\stopromannumeral10}\show\test
\expandafter\def\expandafter\test\expandafter{\romannumeral\stopromannumeral\ten}\show\test
\expandafter\def\expandafter\test\expandafter{\romannumeral010}\show\test
\expandafter\def\expandafter\test\expandafter{\romannumeral0\ten}\show\test
\bye```  (I don't use `\romannumeral0 10` because that can be affected by `\uppercase`/`\lowercase`.)

Comment: yes but you don't need `\chardef\stopromannumeral=\`\^^00 ` as that is `\chardef\stopromannumeral=0`  the `^^@` weirdness is doing nothing there. so you could use `\z@`  but also as you are adding the romannumeral you can simply not add it rather than adding it followed by this guard. `\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^@` is not affected by upper or lowercasing (that's why you use `\^^@`  not the form without backslash

Comment: the whole use of `\romannumeral` in these contexts relies on an explict backtick expression following, if you don't have that then you don't need romannumeral at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I already admitted that the `\chardef`-assignment itself can be written in a more simple way. But when using `\romannumeral` for triggering expansion, as ⟨number⟩ a ⟨chardef-token⟩ denoting a non-positive value can be used. That stops expansion without yielding whatsoever tokens. And cannot be affected by `\lowercase`/`\uppercase` while in a weird context s.b. might give the backtick a strange `\lccode`/`\uccode`...

Comment: this isn't the place for discssion really but the only reason to use romannumeral is to trigger a quirk in the backtick parsing that forces expansion of following tokens, if you do not follow it by a backtick you can simply remove `\romannumeral` as it is doing nothing useful

Comment: you can hide it from uppercase: `\def\foo{\romannumeral\`\^^@} ... \uppercase{\foo...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151495/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-cattleya).

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thanks for spotting the double hash.

Comment: @Cattleya You are welcome. In case `\PlaceCategoryOneOrTwoTokenBehindArgument` is to place a category 1 character token, only that is placed while the argument is gobbled. Seems that is intended behavior, but the name of the macro raises the expectation of someone having accomplished the task of placing an unbalanced opening brace behind a macro argument using Knuthian TeX and expansion-methods only.